# How to set up a "save pic as pdf" button in GUI

Tags: r, user-interface

1) I used the package `gWidget` to make a GUI in R. I have had some problems. I want to add a "save" button in the window, but I don't know how to store the pic already drawn in `ggraphics`.

```
library("memoise")
library("gWidgets2RGtk2")
library("RGtk2")
library("digest")
library("gWidgets2")
library("stats")
options(guiToolkit="RGtk2")
d<-0

#the main window to make and some parts of it to make
win <- gwindow("Load curve analysis", visible=TRUE,expand = TRUE) 
biggroup <- ggroup(horizontal = FALSE, container=win, expand = TRUE)
topgroup<-ggroup(horizontal = TRUE, container=biggroup,expand = TRUE)
bottomgroup<-ggroup(horizontal = TRUE, container=biggroup, expand = TRUE)
leftgroup<-ggroup(horizontal = FALSE, container=bottomgroup,expand= TRUE)
rightgroup<-ggroup(horizontal = FALSE, container=bottomgroup,expand=TRUE)
add(rightgroup, ggraphics(), expand=TRUE)

#draw a pic
updatePlot <- function(h,...) { 
    if(d==1){
        if(svalue(Analyse1)=="Month duration curve")
            plot(1:100,1:100,main="1")

        if(svalue(Analyse1)=="Month load curve")
            plot(1:100,1:100,main="2")
    }
    if(d==2){
        if(svalue(Analyse2)=="Jahresdauerlinie"){
            plot(1:100,1:100,main="3")
        }
    }

}
#the "save" button to make, this button will bring another window,
#but after setting up the road of the saving place, this smaller window will be closed
Store<-gbutton("Save as pdf",container=topgroup, handler = function(h,...){
    win1 <- gwindow("set up road", visible=TRUE,expand = TRUE) 
    group <- ggroup(horizontal = FALSE, container=win1, expand = TRUE)
    tmp <- gframe("Pls type the place you want to save in", container=group)
    obj0<-gedit("",cont=tmp,expand = TRUE)
    tmp <- gframe("Pls name the new diagram, and end it with .pdf", container=group)
    obj1<-gedit("Lastganganalyse.pdf",cont=tmp,expand = TRUE)
    #here the function recordPlot will be used,but it doesnt work,the document cant be opened
    ok<-gbutton("Ok",container=group, handler = function(h,...){
        p<-recordPlot()
        # I dont know why this record Plot doesnt work
        setwd(svalue(obj0))
        pdf(svalue(obj1))
        p
        dev.off()
        dispose(win1)
    })

})

#the other parts of the main window
tmp <- gframe("Year(after input a year pls press Enter)", container=leftgroup)
#Jahren <- gradio(c(2012,2013,2014), horizontal=FALSE, cont=tmp, handler=updatePlot) 
Jahren<-gedit("2012",cont=tmp, handler=updatePlot)
tmp <- gframe("Month", container=leftgroup)
Monat <- gslider(from=1,to=12,by=1, value=1, cont=tmp, handler=updatePlot) 
tmp <- gframe("Analysis' way of a month", container=leftgroup)
Analyse1 <- gcombobox(c(" ","Month duration curve","Month load curve"), cont=tmp, handler=function(h,...){
    d<<-1 
    updatePlot(h,...)
},expand = TRUE) 
tmp <- gframe("Analysis' way of a year", container=leftgroup)
Analyse2 <- gcombobox(c(" ","Jahresdauerlinie"),cont=tmp,handler=function(h,...){
    d<<-2 
    updatePlot(h,...)},expand = TRUE)
```

[image: The GUI I made]

2) Besides, I don't know how to set up the size of the `ggroup`. Or how can I control all parts of the window's size to look better. I dont know that kind of function.

3) The line which is drawn in `ggraphics` is hard to be seen. And how can I change this situation?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide the necessary code / data to reproduce your situation. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we had the following plot in the graphics:

```
ggplot(dat = data.frame("x" = 1:100, "y" = rnorm(100)), aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point()
```

Within the handler for the button, you can try the following:

```
setwd(svalue(obj0))
dev.copy2pdf(file = svalue(obj1))
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried to use the function recordPlot, but it doesnt work in my program, I dont know why. Now I stick my all program (except the concrete funciton  plot) here. I f you have time, can you help me? Sincerely Fangjing

Comment: I cannot run your code fully because there are some missing functions. However, I have plotted within the ggraphics widget and was able to save the plot by doing:

`setwd(svalue(obj0)); dev.copy2pdf(file = svalue(obj1))`.

Try this and let me know if it works.

Comment: Thank you! dev.copy2pdf(file=svalue(obj1)) doesnt work in my computer, the program stoped there. I have changed the plot function in the describtion of this question, so you may run it on your computer. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I tried the following on both Windows and Mac and it worked:
`ok<-gbutton("Ok",container=group, handler = function(h,...){
    setwd(svalue(obj0))
    dev.copy2pdf(file = svalue(obj1))
    dispose(win1)
  })`
Do you get any error on your side? If not, is the PDF at least being created?